# grep for path in process(ps) containing number

Tags: grep, centos

I would like to grep for process path which has a variable. Example -
This is one of the proceses running.

**`/var/www/vhosts/rcsdfg/psd_folr/rcerr-m-deve-udf-172/bin/magt queue:consumers:start customer.import_proditns --single-thread --max-messages=1000`**

I would like to grep for **"psd_folr/rcerr-m-deve-udf-172/bin/magt queue"** from the running processes.
The catch is that the number 172 keeps changing, but it will be a 3 digit number only. Please suggest, I tried below but it is not returning any output.

**`sudo ps axu | grep  "psd_folr/rcerr-m-deve-udf-'^[0-9]$'/bin/magt queue"`**

Comment: Replace `'^[0-9]$'` with `[0-9]\{3\}`

Comment: No, i still get a blank output. But there are proceses running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most relevant section of your regular expression is `-'^[0-9]$'/` which has following problems:

- the apostrophes have no syntactical meaning to grep other than *read an apostrophe*
- the caret `^` matches the beginning of a line, but there is no beginning of a line in `ps`'s output at this place
- the dollar `$` matches the end of a line, but there is no end of a line in `ps`'s output at this place
- you want to read 3 digits but `[0-9]` will only match a single one

Thus, the part of your expression should be modified like this `-[0-9]+/` to match any number of digits (`+` matches the preceding character any number of times but at least once) or like this `-[0-9]{3}/` to match exactly three times (`{n}` matches the preceding character exactly `n` times).

If you alter your command, give `grep` the `-E` flag so it uses extended regular expressions, otherwise you need to escape the plus or the braces:

```
sudo ps axu | grep -E "psd_folr/rcerr-m-deve-udf-[0-9]+/bin/magt queue"
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer

Comment: @Cornholio, Thanks, This works. And thanks for the explanation.